# "guitar tuner" how do you say in german

Tags: translation

"guitar tuner" how do you say in german?

Answer (score 4):

I've never heard *Gitarrenstimmer* like gnasher says. I've always used *Gitarrenstimmgerät* which would translate to *guitar tune gadget*.

Source: Having played classical guitar for 11 years.

Comment: Simply "Stimmgerät"!

Answer (score -1):

Gitarrenstimmer. Gitarrenstimmer.